# Proguard error after adding Glide v4

Tags: android, proguard, android-glide

I am not able to generate the apk with proguard enabled after adding glide v4 library.
I have added the below lines in proguard-rules

```
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public class * extends com.bumptech.glide.AppGlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.ImageHeaderParser$** {
  **[] $VALUES;
  public *;
}
```

It's showing the below error while building.

> Warning:com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.bitmap_recycle.LruBitmapPool:
>   can't find referenced field 'android.graphics.Bitmap$Config HARDWARE'
>   in library class android.graphics.Bitmap$Config

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's save to ignore these warning using:

```
-dontwarn com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.bitmap_recycle.LruBitmapPool
-dontwarn com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.Downsampler
-dontwarn com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.HardwareConfigState
```

See this [post](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2354#issuecomment-327925247)

Answer (score 2):

**Proguard**

If you use proguard, you may need to add the following lines to your proguard.cfg:

```
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public class * extends com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.ImageHeaderParser$** {
  **[] $VALUES;
  public *;
}
```

If you're `targeting any API level less than Android API 27`, also include:

```
-dontwarn com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.VideoDecoder
```

VideoDecoder uses API 27 APIs which may cause proguard warnings even though the newer APIs won’t be called on devices with older versions of Android.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you take your proguard rules from [this glide page](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/download-setup.html#proguard) but it is miswritten. Replace below line

`-keep public class * extends com.bumptech.glide.AppGlideModule`

with this:

`-keep public class * extends com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule`

as you see, `module` package is missing. It is also properly documented [on README page](https://github.com/bumptech/glide#proguard). You can also check your `AppGlideModule` class path from **External Libraries**.

Comment: This is already corrected in their proguard page.

Answer (score -1):

You can as well increase your `compileSdkVersion` to 26. This takes care of the new features that Glide v4 uses.