# Glide 4.11.0 ProGuard QMediaStoreUriLoader$QMediaStoreUriFetcher Error

Tags: android, proguard, android-glide

**When I try to sign the apk, I get these two error messages:**

```
com.bumptech.glide.load.model.stream.QMediaStoreUriLoader$QMediaStoreUriFetcher: can't find referenced method 'boolean isExternalStorageLegacy()' in library class android.os.Environment
com.bumptech.glide.load.model.stream.QMediaStoreUriLoader$QMediaStoreUriFetcher: can't find referenced method 'android.net.Uri setRequireOriginal(android.net.Uri)' in library class android.provider.MediaStore
```

**I went through these two issues, but they are different error messages**

[Proguard error after adding Glide v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46232898/proguard-error-after-adding-glide-v4)

https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2807